# Classifying the Christoffel symbols?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

Given an arbitrary set of Christoffel symbols for a spacetime. How does one identify the Euler, Coriolis force, centrifugal force and linear fictitious force? I suspect it should be possible to do it both from the metric and Christoffel symbols?

Comment: If you are really interested in inertial forces in general relativity, rather than using coordinate-based definitions, I would recommend covariant approach, such as in 
[Abramowicz et al.](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/10/10/001) (Note, Abramowicz has published a lot of papers on related topics with various collaborators).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a completely general way to classify them. For example, if we look at a rectilinear rotating reference frame then we get $$\Gamma{}^x{}_{tt}=-\omega^2 x$$
$$\Gamma{}^y{}_{tt}=-\omega^2 y$$
$$\Gamma{}^x{}_{ty}=\Gamma{}^x{}_{yt}=-\Gamma{}^y{}_{tx}=-\Gamma{}^y{}_{xt}=-\omega$$ And if we write the geodesic equations we get that a force free particle has an acceleration given by $$\ddot x = \omega^2 x + 2 \omega \dot y$$$$\ddot y = \omega^2 y - 2\omega \dot x$$$$\ddot z=0$$ where all of the dots are derivatives with respect to $t$.

Here we recognize the $\omega^2$ terms as being the centrifugal force. The centrifugal force depends on the position in the rotating frame, and points away from the origin. It stems from the Christoffel symbols with the $tt$ in the bottom two slots. We also recognize the $\omega$ terms as being the Coriolis force. The Coriolis force depends on the velocity in the rotating frame, and points perpendicular to the velocity and the axis of rotation. We see that those stem from the Christoffel symbols with the $xt$ and $yt$ in the bottom two slots.

So we might classify Christoffel symbols into fictitious forces based on the bottom two slots where position-dependent fictitious forces are Christoffel symbols with $tt$ while velocity-dependent fictitious forces are mixed like $xt$ and so forth.

But now let's look at spherical coordinates. There is no acceleration going on, so in some sense you could say that there should be no fictitious forces. Indeed, there are no Christoffel symbols involving $t$ at all. All of the Christoffel symbols have a pair of spatial coordinates in the bottom two slots: $$\Gamma{}^r{}_{\theta\theta}=-r$$$$\Gamma^r{}_{\phi\phi}=-r \sin(\theta)^2$$$$\Gamma^\theta{}_{r \theta}=\Gamma^\theta{}_{\theta r}=\Gamma^\phi{}_{\phi r}=\Gamma^\phi{}_{r \phi}=\frac{1}{r}$$$$\Gamma^\theta{}_{\phi \phi}=-\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$$$$\Gamma^\phi{}_{\theta\phi}=\Gamma^\phi{}_{\phi\theta}=\cot(\theta)$$with the geodesics: $$\ddot r=r\dot \theta^2 + r\sin(\theta)^2\dot \phi^2$$$$\ddot \theta=\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\dot \phi^2-\frac{2}{r}\dot r \dot \theta$$$$\ddot \phi=-\frac{2}{r}\dot r \dot \phi-2 \cot(\theta)\dot \theta \dot \phi$$

On the one hand, all of these terms are quadratic in velocity. So they can be distinguished in that manner in the geodesics. However, practically they nevertheless share some similarities to fictitious forces. As $r$ decreases and gets small the $\dot r \dot \theta$ term for $\ddot \theta$ indicates that $\dot \theta$ will increase rapidly, a sort of angular Coriolis-like force. This in turn will lead to an increase in the $r\dot \theta^2$ term of $\ddot r$, a sort of centrifugal-like force. Although neither of these is usually considered a fictitious force, in some sense that radial centrifugal-like force does push particles away from the origin.

Things become even more complicated for non-static and non-stationary spacetimes and coordinates, or charts that do not have a single timelike coordinate. The general rules become murky, but this should give you a flavor for what you can do in simple cases.

Comment: Hey the comment by AVS suggests something different

Comment: @MoreAnonymous he is welcome to expand it to a full answer. Frankly, a covariant approach to fictitious forces makes no sense